# Can logical operator be used with in ternary operators in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator, logical-operators

Is this statement correct in PHP

```
$abc = $x === "" || $y !== $z ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not. I believe it will work. Just put parenthesis. Like

`$abc = ($x === "" || $y !== $z) ? "true" : "false";`

Comment: Most of the time condition works same everywhere. Every condition will evaluated as true or false anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes. it works correctly.

```
$x = 1;
$y = 2;

$z = 100;

$abc = $x === "" || $y !== $z ? "true" : "false";

var_dump($abc); // true
```

and

```
$x = 1;
$y = 100;

$z = 100;

$abc = $x === "" || $y !== $z ? "true" : "false";

var_dump($abc); // false
```

but, please, use parenthesis!

```
$abc = ($x === "" || $y !== $z) ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it out and it works absolutely fine. You just need to add round brackets for the condition statement
So your code will look like this

```
$abc = ($x === "" || $y !== $z) ? "true" : "false";
echo $abc;
```